# jQuery - split() arrays with only one match = undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem with the `split()` function. 
I get the error undefined but it dont know why :/

It is easier to explain with a working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/415/

```
$(function start()
{
    css('#div { font-color:#ff0000; border:1px solid #00ff00; }', '#div_2 { font-color:#ff0000; }', '#line2 { font-color:#00ffff; }');
});


function css(c0,c1,c2)
{
    if(c0 != 'undefined')
    {
        c0_selector = c0.match(/^.*{/);
        c0 = c0.replace(/^.*{/,'');
        c0 = c0.replace(/}/,'');
        c0_arr = c0.split(';');        
        values = new Array();
        values[0] = new Array();
        values[0][0] = c0_selector;  
        for (i = 1; i < c0_arr.length; i++)
        {
            values[0][i]= c0_arr[i].split(':');
        }
    }

    if(c1 != 'undefined')
    {
        c1_selector = c1.match(/^.*{/);
        c1 = c1.replace(/^.*{/,'');
        c1 = c1.replace(/}/,'');
        c1_arr = c1.split(';');  
        values[1] = new Array();        
        values[1][0] = c1_selector;
        for (i = 1; i < c1_arr.length; i++)
        {
            values[1][i]= c1_arr[i].split(':');
        }
    }

    $('#log').append(''+values[0][0]+'<br />');  
    $('#log').append(''+values[0][1][0]+'<br />');          
    $('#log').append(''+values[0][1][1]+'<br />');   
    $('#log').append('<hr />');  
    $('#log').append(''+values[1][0]+'<br />');      
    $('#log').append(''+values[1][1][0]+'<br />');          
    $('#log').append(''+values[1][1][1]+'<br />');       

    $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $.toJSON(values),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function() {
                alert('success');
            }
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loops are wrong.

```
c0_arr = c0.split(';');
```

You get indexes 0 and 1 containing stuff after that.

And then you loop like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < c0_arr.length; i++)
{
   values[0][i]= c0_arr[i].split(':');
}
```

Starting at index 1. 
You should start at index 0, and fill your values array like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < c0_arr.length; i++)
{
   values[0][i+1]= c0_arr[i].split(':');
}
```

Then you will get all your values where they belong.

Previous answer explains clearly why you get the undefined error BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the lines logging your values array, was it so hard to add lines logging the other vars?

```
c1_arr = c1.split(';');
```

The array created here is ['font-color:#ff0000', ''] - there is a blank second element since there's nothing after the ';' in the input string.

Then when you call:

```
values[1][i]= c1_arr[i].split(':');
```

c1_arr[1] is empty string, so values[1][1] is an array with only one element, empty string.

values[1][1][0] -> empty string
values[1][1][1] -> undefined (no second element)